# Context with Teams Toolkit (MS Teams Bot)- all information is gone on bot update

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

So, im building a teams bot using teams toolkit extension in vs code. This is a organization internal use application and the issue that im running into is that whenever i update the bot it loses the context for all the members. The only way to get it back is to message the bot in the general channel with everyone in it. Is there a workaround here? I can imagine im the first one with this problem. My understanding of the issue is that with each update, the cache is cleared and by messaging in the general channel we are generating a context for each user (aka the member object i am targetting to send the notification)

**First time posting- please let me know if more information is required

I have already tried storing the conversation_id and conversationReference object to target and send notifications. I have also tried using ms graph to target users for notification from the backend. None of this seems to have worked. This is essentially a notification bot solely- the frontend submits a request, pings the backend and if a notification needs to be sent out, the backend hits the bots endpoints with the appropriate payload.

Comment: What [memory state storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#storage-layer) are you using for the bot?

Comment: Im not 100 percent sure- currently, anytime i update the bot i generate new context by messaging in a teams group channel with the bot in it. This way it creates a conversation for every user. Its less than ideal but i dont believe im storing the state anywhere(is that possible?)

Comment: also when i said i tried storing the information i meant i sent the conversation_id to my backend as a response from the bot and my backend stored it so my table (probably not the best way to do this)

Comment: When a bot is updated, it typically involves restarting or redeploying the bot's code or configuration. During this process, in-memory data, including member context stored within the bot's runtime environment, is lost.
We can use storage solution, such as a database or cache to retrieve context.

Comment: it seems like every method i attempt to use is deprecated. has anyone set up a storage for a bot recently.  Would it be possible to just create a blob storage in azure and just set up a connection to write to it on conversations? also, what exactly would i need to store to send users messages going forward

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're using the default local file storage, Azure web app and Azure Functions clean up the local file during a restart or redeploy. You need to implement your own storage to persist the conversation reference.

You can refer to the Add Storage part of this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/notification-bot-in-teams?tabs=ts1%2Cts2%2Cts3%2Cts4%2Cjsts%2Cts5#add-storage) for more info.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).